# How do isolated power amplifiers function when connected in series

Tags: current, isolation, power-amplifier, push-pull

I'm working on an isolated power amplifier with a differential output. This is achieved through two power op amps driven anti-phase to one another, simplistically it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEFxuG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is all working fine and has been prototyped to deliver +/-50V output up to 1A pulsed. Now the idea has been floated that we could connect multiple of these output stages together in series to achieve higher voltage (within isolation breakdown limits). It sounds all well and good to me as each stage runs from its own isolated power supply but I'm having a hard time visualizing the current flow.

Considering a positive output signal where the OUT+ drives close to the supply rail and the OUT- sinks current to its local IGND, does charge from stage 1 flow through the load into IGND2 then back out through V2 and finally into IGND1? And what would be the mechanism for the charge moving from IGND2 to V2, supply rail capacitors?

Or does this topology even work at all while we're at it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDt0aw.png)</sup>

Comment: One problem will be how to isolate the common ground on the inputs. You could use a transformer. Capacitance to ground might be another problem.

Comment: Ah, inputs to the Op Amps are all generated locally by DACs that are controlled digitally over opto-isolators so no common ground there.